# How to deal with VBA error inside of a class?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am having a hard time figuring out the right way of handling unexpected errors inside of a custom class. If there is an error in any of my classes it causes a radical failure of the application. I cannot seem to figure out the best method of passing errors back to the calling procedure if the class object has instantiated successfully.

Suppose I try to set the age of someone in my class with `Person.age=21` and there is an error in the `Property Let` code. How do I trap an unexpected error and give it back to the calling procedure? Then I want to fail gracefully.

I use MS Access to do a bunch of reports in MS Excel and if my application runs into an unexpected error and fails, it leaves hidden MS Excel workbooks open. I would like to catch these errors and then close everything so nothing is hanging.

I don't t really need specific code so much as I need an idea, thought process, or the correct procedure order.

PS: The majority of my subs, functions, and properties have error handling

Comment: You can circumvent the problem by using stand-alone VB6 instead of VBA. Look & feel the same + many added benefits (incl. debugging errors inside classes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are basically two options:

1) Raise an error from your class code up to the calling code (maybe do this only after trying and failing to handle the error within your class).  If you re-raise errors then you should consider adding relevant error messages which might help the caller figure out what went wrong.

2) Swallow all errors within your class methods, and use some other way to indicate to the calling code that something has gone wrong (such as e.g. having a boolean property "OK" in your class, which calling code can check to ensure everything went fine during whatever method it called in your class).

The first option is probably the preferred way, though it is of course a matter of preference, and would be swayed by whether, for example, you are the only person writing code against your class.

Comment: Thank you Tim.  I hope to share my classes with others so I don't want the calling procedure to have to deal with class internal errors.  I think I might have to do a better process of validation before using classes.

Answer (score 2):

VBA error handling goes something like this:

```
Public Sub DoSomething()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    'Do some stuff...

    Exit Sub

    ErrHandler:
       MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbOKOnly, "Error"
End Sub
```

Comment: very ugly and cumbersome :-( (but thanks for the answer and clear code)